# Zip creation based on path provided in cells

Tags: excel, vba

1. provide path of files or folder in certain range of cells.
2. read those cells and copy those files/folder to a new folder.
3. create a zip of that folder.

Sample input:
[image: sample input]

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim rngFile As Range, cel As Range
    Dim desPath As String, filename As String

    Set rngFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("A3", "A5") 

    desPath = "C:\test\"

    For Each cel In rngFile
        If Dir(cel) <> "" Then
            filename = Dir(cel) 
            FileCopy cel, desPath & filename
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I am able to read and copy files but not able to copy folder. any way such it can copy files as well as folder which is mentioned in cells.

Comment: See https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm for copying a folder and its contents

Comment: Anything here in this code we could add to copy both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Const DEST_PATH As String = "C:\test\" 'use const for fixed values
    Dim rngFile As Range, cel As Range, p, fso As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set rngFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Instructions").Range("A3:A5") ' : not ,

    For Each cel In rngFile.Cells
        cel.Font.Color = vbBlack
        p = Trim(cel.Value)
        If fso.FolderExists(p) Then     'is this a folder?
            fso.copyfolder p, DEST_PATH
        ElseIf fso.FileExists(p) Then   'is this a file?
            fso.copyfile p, DEST_PATH
        Else
            cel.Font.Color = vbRed      'not an existing file or folder
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Any way such that we can check for these files from a GitHub repo.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea....